# Return asp.net chart within a .net user control (asp:wizard)

Tags: asp.net, charts

I have tried googling around for some related stuff on this all afternoon to no avail so I hope some of you guys can help me out.

I am using an asp:wizard user control which collect various values from a user and displays these on a final "results page" in the form of a table.

I have created a separate "GraphEngine" class which takes a Bool parameter deciding which Chart Type to create (line/Stacked Column)

```
//T13 is selection of line/stacked column chart type.
public Chart GetChart(bool T13)
    {

        Chart chart = new Chart();

        //define some shared properties no matter which ChartType.
        chart.Width = 900;
        chart.Height = 500;
        chart.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1");
        chart.Series.Add("Costs");
        chart.Series.Add("Stages");
        chart.Legends.Add("Legend1");

        if (T13 == true)
        {
            //chart = charttype1 and add values from Dictionary<string, bool>
        }
        else
        {
            //chart = charttype2 and add values..............
        }
        return chart;

    }
```

I then call GetChart in the final step of the Wizard Control (acsx.cs file).

```
GraphEngine GE = new GraphEngine(GraphData);
System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart Chart =  GE.GetChart(t13);
//What should I be saying here to render Chart as "Chart" rather than literal
LiteralGraph.Text =  GE.GetChart(getSetGraphData, t13).ToString();
```

I am not sure how to render the chart

Chart with ID "Chart" is on the .ascx page - shouldn't this just populate with returned info from GE.GetChart(t13); ?

NB: If I create/define all chart values and axis etc within the user control wizard step, it returns fine but I need to separate the graph generation as there are  lots of lines of code (validation etc) in ascx.cs file and so I would like to separate my 150 odd lines from that. This is probably the "right" way to do things?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're returning actual chart control - you need to add it to a control collection on the form. For example, make `LiteralGraph` instead of Literal - a Panel and then you can do:

```
LiteralGraph.Controls.Add(GE.GetChart(getSetGraphData, t13));
```

Comment: Great - thanks Yuriy.  I knew the literal wasn't right but I wasn't sure how to correct it. Working perfectly.